# Cannot understand call tree view of jprofiler

Tags: performance-testing, jprofiler, invocation

I am new to jprofiler and i am not able to understand what invocations means, 
1)If one method is taking 1 invocation how come the each sub methods are taking more than 1 invocation?
2)And the time is for per invocation or is it total time taken for total number of invocations?
3)And in [screenshot of my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqqqJ.png)what is the total %, for example one method is taking 21.6% so all the sub-methods should add up and they should be 21.6% but that is not the case here.

It would be really helpful if someone can explain me the call tree view.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

1.In the image[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yn2aw.jpg) i have highlighted the time 869s in 91 inv, i wanted to know how to find out time for 1 invocation because when i divide 869/91= 9.54 but when i check my logs that service is taking less than 1s.
Can you please explain it to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1)If one method is taking 1 invocation how come the each sub methods are taking more than 1 invocation?

For example: Method A can be called once and it can call method B 10 times.

> 2)And the time is for per invocation or is it total time taken for total number of invocations?

It is the total time for all invocations.

> 3)And in screenshot of my resultwhat is the total %, for example one method is taking 21.6% so all the sub-methods should add up and they should be 21.6% but that is not the case here.

The remainder is "self-time".

See

https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/jprofiler/help/doc/#jprofiler.cpu

for a detailed explanation.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not understand "The remainder is self-time.". And i have went to the document watched your videos on YouTube but i did not get what i wanted. I have edited my ans i would really appreciate if you help me with this.

Comment: Self time is the time that is not covered by child nodes, either by direct bytecode execution or through invocation of filtered classes and methods. I cannot comment on the times in your call tree, these are measurements. Maybe some of your invocations take longer than others.

Comment: Actually i wanted to know is there anyway we can calculate time for one invocation ?

Comment: If you want to see single invocations, right-click the method and choose "Add as an exceptional method", you will then see the slowest method invocations separately.